# Include parts of table in separate php file

Tags: php, file, include, extract

I would like to be able to include certain parts of an HTML table in a separate php file. So, for example, I may have a table that is like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Pos.</td><td>No.</td><td>Driver</td><td>Car</td><td>Points</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.</td><td>77</td><td>Andrew Jordan</td><td>Honda Civic</td><td>346</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to be able to do is to extract ONLY the cells for pos, driver and points, so that the table could be rendered in a different php file without having to manually copy and edit it each time.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Pos.</td><td>Driver</td><td>Points</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.</td><td>Andrew Jordan</td><td>346</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do this with a 'class' or a php 'include'? I know that you can include entire php files, but what about extracting very specific parts of a file?

Comment: I highly suggest you start coding in a Model View Controller framework, a quick google search would give you tons of useful info. In short, the main purpose of MVC is to separate your templates from your logic, which in turn allows you to access your templates or parts of your template whenever you need them, without the need to rewrite any html.

Answer (score 0):

table.php

```
$table = "<table>
<tr><td>Pos.</td><td>Driver</td><td>Points</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.</td><td>Andrew Jordan</td><td>346</td></tr>
</table>";
```

table2.php

```
include("table.php");

print $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a reusable code to generate such partial outputs, you could consider using output buffering.

write a function like this:-

```
function get_output($file_name,$parameters = NULL)
{
include $filename;
ob_start();

//The included file generates the output required using $parameters

return ob_get_clean();
}
```

then in your main file you use:-

```
$output = get_output($file_name,$parameters);
echo $output; // gives the output generated inside get_output function
```

in your case just store the code in a file, say 'table.php' and then

```
$output = get_output('table.php',NULL);
```

[reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#109088)